# MediaRecorder start failed -19, start failed, try to delete broken file

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have a surface view in my app that works fine but as well as having a video preview on screen I would also like to record the video at the same time. To do this I have:

Declared variables etc:

```
/************************ GLOBAL VARIABLES FOR VIDEO PREVIEW ********************/

/* For the surface view */
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

/* For saving the video to the device */
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

/* For both */
Button buttonStartCameraPreview, buttonStopCameraPreview;
Camera camera;
boolean previewing = false;
```

Then in the onCreate method() initiate the recorder, set up start/stop buttons, set up the surface view and then code to activate the surface view / video capture as per button press:

```
// Set up the media recorder
initMediaRecorder();

buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startCameraPreview);
buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopCameraPreview);

surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
// Set the surfaceView so it appears on top, not behind the view
surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
// Set the surfaceView background colour to magenta
surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(!previewing)
        {
            camera = Camera.open();
            if (camera != null)
            {
                try 
                {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    previewing = true;
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
buttonStopCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(camera != null && previewing)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            finish();
            camera = null;
            previewing = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Other methods of relevance are:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{
    prepareMediaRecorder();
}
```

And:

```
/************************ SETTING UP MEDIARECORDER METHODS ************************/

public void initMediaRecorder()
{
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); // DEFAULT
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA); //DEFAULT
    //CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    //mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    //mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/" + System.nanoTime() + "_video.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile().toString());
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
}

public void prepareMediaRecorder()
{
     mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
     try 
     {
         mediaRecorder.prepare();
     } 
     catch (IllegalStateException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

public static File getOutputMediaFile()
{
    // External sd card location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) 
    {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) 
        {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    File mediaFile;
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    return mediaFile;
}
```

The application loads up fine but it is when I press the button to start surface view/recording that the "app has stopped message" occurs (the surface view still works in the background).

I assume the problem is related (as per LogCat) with creating/overwriting the destination file to save output but I can't put my finger on it. CatLog below:

```
07-13 19:12:14.608: E/MediaRecorder(25372): start failed: -19
07-13 19:12:14.608: E/MediaRecorder(25372): start failed.
07-13 19:12:14.608: E/MediaRecorder(25372): try to delete broken file:    /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Hello Camera/VID_20140713_191211.mp4
```

I also have in the Manifest file:

```
<!-- Accessing camera hardware -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The videos were being saved to my phone (had to download ASTRO file manager to find them), however it was still crashing.

Comment: Thanks. Will advise if I find a solution